# How to get correct values from getBoundingClientRect if page is scrolled on initial load

Tags: javascript, getboundingclientrect

So have experienced a small issue with getBoundingClientRect and im not sure how to work around.

If i retrieve the initial Values of an Elements getBoundingClientRect i get correct rect.top and rect.y values. But if i scroll down the Page, reload and then retrieve the Values, the rect.top and rect.y values are now different, they represent the y position from new Page start Position.

Does anyone know a working workaround?

Comment: The rect should update when you scroll. You just have to get it again after every scroll event.

Comment: Are you getting the values after the `load` event?

Comment: Thank you @caTS this solved the issue. But what to do if i want the y position of the whole Document?

Comment: What does that mean? What's the "y position of the whole document"?